# Should a stationary set of an ordinal contain all it's limit poins?

Tags: set-theory

Should a stationary set of an ordinal contain all it's limit poins?

By a stationary set I refer to Jech's definition: If $k$ is a cardinal then a set $S \subset K$ is called stationary if $S \cap C \neq \emptyset$ for every closed unbounded set $C \subset k$

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. This would make it closed. Stationary sets are sets which are "big" but not quite closed.

For example, $\omega\cup[\omega_1,\omega_2)$ is a stationary subset of $\omega_2$. It's not closed because $\omega$ is not an element of that set, but it is a limit point of it. In fact this set contains a club (of $\omega_2$).

Typically sets of the form $\{\alpha<\kappa\mid\operatorname{cf}(\alpha)=\lambda\}$ are stationary sets which are not closed, granted $\lambda<\kappa$, and $\kappa>\omega_1$ (otherwise this is the set of limit ordinals below $\omega_1$ which is closed). To see that this is not closed, note that any increasing sequence of length which has cofinality $\neq\lambda$ will be missing its limit point.