# Does a stationary set of a regular cardinal $k$ always contain a segment $(\alpha,k)$ for some $\alpha<k$

Tags: set-theory

As a continuation to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1026389/should-a-stationary-set-of-an-ordinal-contain-all-its-limit-poins) question.

Suppose that $A$ is a stationary set of a regular ordinal $k=[0,k)$. Does this equivalent to saying that $A$ contains a subset of the form $(\alpha,k)$ for some ordinal $\alpha < k$?

I tried to prove it to myself:

First direction: If $A$ contains a subset of the form $(\alpha,k)$ for some ordinal $\alpha < k$, then, obviously, every unbounded set of $k$ should intersect $A$.

Second direction: Suppose that $A$ is not stationary. Then there exists a club (closed unbounded) set $C$ for which $A \cap C = \emptyset$. If $A$ would contain a segment of the form $(\alpha,k)$
 this would imply that $C$ is bounded by $\alpha$.

Am I correct?

By a stationary set I refer to Jech's definition: If $k$ is a cardinal then a set $S \subset K$ is called stationary if $S \cap C \neq \emptyset$ for every closed unbounded set $C \subset k$

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is much much much stronger.

First of all, note that $[\alpha,\kappa)$ is always a closed and unbounded subset of $\kappa$. So any set containing a tail segment necessarily contains a club.

On the other hand, the set of limit ordinals below $\kappa$ is also a club, but contains no tail segment. So not even every club contains such a subset.

Stationary sets can be very complicated, much like how "sets of positive measure" can end up being very complicated in the unit interval.